# Error found in Json File

Tags: .net, json, visual-studio-2013

Using VS 2013.

During the creation of a Windows store app, I added a json file to the project, and added data inside:

```
{"Events":
[
  {
    "UniqueId": "Day-1-Item-1",
    "Name": "Item Title: 1",
    "Place": "Item Subtitle: 1",
    "Description": "Event 1",
    "Start" : "11.02",
    "End" : "12.05",
    "Image" : "Assets/appbar.calendar.png"
  }
]
}
```

All works perfect, but after binding in project i got the message, that the JSON file contains an error inside.

[image]

Question: Where is the error inside of this file?

Comment: Is there some weird hidden character it is complaining about?

Comment: try to clean it by copy to notepad and then insert back... Only Enter, space and Tab lefts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh, finally found - my file has name `EventsData.json` instead of `EventData.json`. So due to using of this Binding source to designere view, during launching all data can be displayed correctlly.

So, correct variant is `Source=/DataModel/EventsData.json`

Heh, spend few hours for finding such small typo...